# Can't log in to new 14.04 install

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, login

I have just installed Lubuntu 14.04 and can't log in. I get incorrect password, even though I just added and confirmed password during setup. I did not set up any users during setup just a root password.

Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: possible your answer here http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Answer (score 0):

By default while installation ubuntu does not set root password. It creates a default User, based on what you enter in "Enter your Name" , and sudo rights are given to it.

Double check if your caps lock was on and try to login from shell (Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2), not with "root" as username.

Comment: As soon as I tried shell login it immediately stated a crash report - mei_me timer: connect/disconnect timeout

Comment: @wiz I recommend editing your question to add as many details as possible about that. That's new information that may be essential to getting an answer. (Though I'd still recommend [trying to reset your password as described here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password).)

Answer (score -1):

At the grub login, drop to root shell and either check if your user is in /etc/passwd and change the user password or add your user.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this to explain how to actually perform those steps. Also, wouldn't `ls /home` be a much easier way to list the username of the system's real human users? (Since most entries in `/etc/passwd` on most desktop systems will not correspond to human users.)